# Upload file through url in django

Tags: python, django, url, file-upload, django-forms

I'm currently creating an app thats supposed to take a input in form of a url (here a PDF-file) and recognize this as a PDF and then upload it to a tmp folder i have on a server.

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed with this. I've already made a form which contains a FileField which works perfectly, but when it comes to urls i have no clue.

Thank you for all answers, and sorry about the lacking english skills.

Comment: start with http://google.com/?q=django+file+upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 4 bytes of a pdf file are `%PDF` so you could just download the first 4 bytes from that url and compare them to `%PDF`. If it matches, then download the whole file.

Example:

```
import urllib2

url = 'your_url'
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
first_four_bytes = req.read(4)

if first_four_bytes == '%PDF':
    pdf_content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    # save to temp folder
else:
    # file is not PDF
```

Comment: I see. This will seem to work nicely. But how do i save the file to the tmp folder? Is it as easy as newdoc= handle_UploadPdf(docfile = request.FILES['docfile']), and then newdoc.save? Or is it more complicated?